# Add conditional styles to v-data-table row

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3, v-data-table, vuetify-datatable

I am trying to apply a CSS class conditionally to a row of a v-data-table component. I saw the item-class prop does not exist in Vuetify 3, so the other solution that was commonly used is to utilize the default slot like this:

```html
<v-data-table 
  :headers="tableHeaders"
  :items="tableItems"
  item-value="id"
>
  <!-- Default Slot -->
  <template #item="{ item }">
    <tr :class="{'bg-red': item.columns.temperature > 28}">
      <td
        v-for="header in tableHeaders"
        :key="header"
      >
        {{ item.columns[header.key] }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </template>
      
  <!-- Temperature Slot -->
  <template #item.temperature="{item}">
    {{ item.columns.temperature }} &deg;C
  </template>
  
  <!-- Humidity Slot -->
  <template #item.humidity="{item}">
    {{ item.columns.humidity }} %
  </template>

  <!-- Id Slot -->
  <template #item.id="{item}">
    <v-btn
      @click="showInfo(item.columns.id)"
    >
      Show Info
    </v-btn>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

```js
const tableHeaders = [
  {
    title: 'Temperature',
    sortable: true,
    key: 'temperature'
  },
  {
    title: 'Humidity',
    sortable: true,
    key: 'humidity'
  },
  {
    title: 'Info',
    sortable: false,
    key: 'id'
  },
]

const tableItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    temperature: 22,
    humidity: 55
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    temperature: 30,
    humidity: 45
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    temperature: 22,
    humidity: 75
  },
]
```

The problem is this way my default slot overwrites the rest of the slots.

How can I conditionally apply a CSS class to rows in a Vuetify v-data-table while maintaining custom slots for other columns?

Answer (score 0):

Your doing wrong here.

```
<tr :class="{'bg-red': item.columns.temperature > 28}">
```

Here how should it done. So I hope it helps.

[Demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Your example still does not work. The default item slot still overwrites other slots.